# How to get this PHP statement array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, pdo

**Data structure**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => aaa
                [age] => 20
                [address] => ccc
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => bbb
                [age] => 25
                [address] => ddd
            )

    )

 $stmt= $conn->query("SELECT name,age,address FROM user" )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 echo $stmt[0]['column name'];
```

how to  get  $stmt[0] as a variable, so whenever more user added I can just call echo $stmt[i]['column name'];  out?

I am trying to achieve

```
echo $stmt[allrecords]['column name'];
```

because I need to call this in javascrpt as var v = array("ccc","ddd");

This var v array is `<?php echo $stmt[allrecords]['column name'];  ?>`

Comment: `$variable = $stmt[0]['column name']`?

Comment: Well, maybe.  Not very clear.

Comment: `$stmt[0]` is already a variable - so no idea what your asking

Comment: thank you for your reply, but this only return the first record result, I was trying to get one column result from each record. so that's why I want $stmt[0] to a variable.

Comment: random guess `foreach($stmt as $x){echo $x['name'];}`

Comment: Show us the data and show us what you would like the result to be.

Comment: Ooooo cool! I llove the random guess game @Dagon ;-)

Comment: I have edited the question, does this making sense to you?

Comment: look at my guess its what you want, just write the js string rather than echo

Comment: Yes, yes! Thank you @Dagon

Comment: @user2983797 fleshed out answer below if you care to accpet it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$names=array();
//loop to get the names
foreach($stmt as $x){
$names[]=$x['name'];//add them to a new array
}

//create js varable
$v='var v = array("'.implode('"',$names).'")';
```

Comment: Thanks again @Dagon, this totally solved my problem, when I have enough  reputation I will vote you :)

Comment: @user2983797 you can accept answers regardless of rep, click the tick to the left of my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry I didn't know there s a rule only vote for one person. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Yes, you can have a puppy. @Dagon

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function.

```
$all_addresses = array_column($stmt, 'address');
echo implode('<br>', $all_addresses);
```